# Passthrough authorization from web-application to web-api

Tags: authentication, authorization, openid-connect

I am designing an new web application with a web-api backend. We want to try using *OpenID Connect* and we are looking into the best way to authorize the user for the API.

Setup:

- User logs in into front-end and gets an OAUTH token.
- Send OAUTH token to web-api to authorize the user
- Return a bearer-token which is needed to authorize further usage of the API.

But I am not finding any information about being able to directly use an OAUTH2 token to pass to the API.

What is the best way to accomplish 'authentication passthrough' for the web-API?